# How to disable e.g. Dropout in tf.keras.Model to generate activation maximation images using transfer learning

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I am using transfer learning and keras.applications.InceptionV3. I manage to train the model successfully.

However, when I want to generate "activation maximisation" images (e.g. the input image that maximizes the activation of one of the custom classes, ref eg  https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.02017v3.pdf ) I struggle to use the pre-trained model since I do manage to use it in "fit" mode and disable all dropouts etc.

What I do is that I combine the pre-trained model in a tf.keras.Sequential to do gradient descent on the weights of the first layer (the input image).

Despite setting base_model.trainable = False however it seems as if the pre-trained model is put into training mode (although weights are not updated) when using model.fit(data) on the outer sequential model.

Is there any way to force the base_model (a child of a Sequential) to be in "predict" mode when calling fit on the outer?

Comment: Did not get exactly what you need, but setting `trainable = False` for all the layers will do the trick. You can check my notebook here https://github.com/michelucci/oreilly-london-ai/blob/master/day2/Transfer%20Learning/Transfer_learning_with_keras_with_files.ipynb for an example. Check if that helps you... If you scroll down you will find several examples of transfer learning.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for late reply - I tried that but did not seem to work - batch normalization still seems to behave strangely ( i think). I will debug some more and report back

Comment: No, trainable = False deinitely does not seem to be enough to make the pre-trained model behave same in training mode as in inference mode :-(

Answer (score 0):

I just came across the same question. After reading some documentation and having a look on the source code of TensorFlows implementations of `tf.keras.layers.Layer`, `tf.keras.layers.Dense`, and `tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization` I got the following understanding.

If `training = False` is passed on calling the layer, it will run in inference mode. This has nothing to do with the attribute `trainable`, which means something different. It would probably lead to less misunderstanding, if they would have called it `training_mode` instead.

When doing Transfer Learning or Fine Tuning `training = False` should be passed on calling the base model itself. As far as I saw until now this will only affect layers like `tf.keras.layers.Dropout` and `tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization` and will have not effect on the other layers.

Running in inference mode via `training = False` will result in `tf.layers.Dropout` not to apply the dropout rate at all.

As `tf.layers.Dropout` has no trainable weights, setting the attribute `trainable = False` will have no effect at all,